# How to transform a 3D array correctly to a 2D array so that you can plot it properly?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

Be informed, I am also using StandardScaler. I'm not sure if that affects anything. I can try to provide reproducible code for that, but perhaps it's not necessary. It may just be a numpy thing.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(60,60,1)
```

Now we plot this, to see the image.

```
cs = plt.imshow(x)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: 60x60x1]

We do this with imshow, which does accept 3D arrays. We need to use contourf, though, which only accepts 2D arrays.

```
x = x.reshape(1, 60*60)
```

Now, I want to plot this, so I want to get it into `(60,60)`. But if I just reshape back to `(60,60)`, the image is distorted.

```
x = x.reshape(60,60)
cs = plt.contourf(x)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: After reshaping to 60x60]

I am specifically asking to reshape it so that 1. It was the same image as the first image, and 2. So that it could be done with contourf, since that this the only function for which a custom color bar is available AFAIK. One can see that the images are different because the max on each color bar is different (0.8 vs 1.05)

Comment: why are you using `contourf` and don't use `imshow` again?

Comment: I could not get the color bar to work with imshow. It was just blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question touches on several different topics, it would help if it was more specific.

First, regarding the shape, I would always try to avoid reshaping yourself (manually), that's only error prone and requires either hard coding the shape or retrieving it with something like `x.shape` etc.

In this case, you can simply drop the redundant "band" dimension by using:
`x = np.squeeze(x)`

That makes Numpy do the work, and preserves the other dimensions as they are.

Secondly, note that `imshow` and `contourf` have a different default origin. You can see this in your post because one image is vertically flipped compared to the other. This becomes obvious if you introduce some "artifact" in your random array.
You can explicitly define the origin yourself if you want control over this.

Lastly, the colors for `contourf` are created by specifying a range (low, high) for the values in between to get a certain color. This is somewhat different compared to the more continuous mapping when using `imshow`. But you can pass a `BoundaryNorm` to `imshow` to make it behave similar to `contourf`.

Sample data:

```py
x = np.random.rand(20, 20, 1)
x[2:8, 2:8] += 0.4
x = np.clip(x, 0, 1)
x = np.squeeze(x)
```

Colormap and Normalizer:

```py
cmap = plt.cm.viridis
bounds = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
```

Plot result:

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(
    1,2, figsize=(10,5), constrained_layout=True, 
    subplot_kw=dict(xticks=[], yticks=[], aspect=1),
)

im = ax1.imshow(x, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, origin='upper')
cb = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax1, orientation='horizontal', shrink=0.5, spacing='proportional')

cs = ax2.contourf(x, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, levels=bounds, origin='upper')
cb = fig.colorbar(cs, ax=ax2, orientation='horizontal', shrink=0.5, spacing='proportional')
```

The interpolation from `contourf` will "erode" the highs and lows a little, making it appear to have slightly less contrast/range.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use `plt.clim(0,1.05)` for changing colorbar range.
is this your answer?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(60,60,1)

cs = plt.imshow(x)
plt.colorbar()
print(x.shape)
plt.show()

x = x.reshape(1, 60*60)

x = x.reshape(60,60)

cs = plt.imshow(x)
plt.colorbar()
plt.clim(0,1.05)
print(x.shape)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT** as you see in output 3d , 2d shape plot same:

[image]

Comment: You must not use imshow, unless you know how to add a color bar to it.

Comment: @mmont what do you mean : `unless you know how to add a color bar to it` what do you need about color bar.

Comment: I can’t figure out how to make a custom color bar unless I use contourf. I tried with imshow() but it did not work.

Comment: @mmont, I edit the answer and add this line : `plt.clim(0,1.05)` for changing colorbar range and also using imshow, is this helping you or no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `plt.gca().set_aspect(1)`

Or for a more generic way if the array is not square: `plt.gca().set_aspect(x.shape[1]/x.shape[0])`

[image: square contourf]

Comment: Does this allow you to customize the color bar, with chosen tick marks? I’ve only found that I can do that with contourf() function.

Comment: Also, you reproduced the second picture, while we want to get the first picture. You can tell by looking at the color bar

Comment: This is fully independent, you can do whatever you want with the contourf and colorbar, `set_aspect` work on the axes container

Comment: Your question is "The image is distorted. How do I reshape it correctly?", which I think I addressed. If you have another question, please make it explicit ;)

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question.

Comment: @mmont very possibly, but please edit your question to make it more explicit

Comment: I specifically asked to reshape it so that 1. It was the same image as the first image, and 2. So that it could be done with contourf, since that this the only function for which a custom color bar is available AFAIK.

Comment: Sure thing, I’ll edit that into the post.

Comment: @mmont I think you need to explicit better the problem. What I understand is that the ascpect ratio is **distorted** (i.e., plot is not square). If this is not the issue, please define *distorted*. IMO there is nothing wrong with the numpy array.

Comment: Distorted as in it is not the same image. The numbers are different, as you can see from the color bar. The first image has a color bar that goes to 0.8 while the second goes to 1.05